# How to visualize the image with more than 3 channels?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

How can I visualize the image in MATLAB that have more than 3 channels?

I have hyperspectral data and I have combined 5 bands together for one single image

```
slice1(:,:,1) = output(:,:,8);
slice1(:,:,2) = output(:,:,12);
slice1(:,:,3) = output(:,:,18);
slice1(:,:,4) = output(:,:,20);
slice1(:,:,5) = output(:,:,22);
```

I have tried to use `imagesc` but it doesn't work.

Comment: What would you like it to look like? Unfortunately, human perception can only really map 3 dimensions to colour. You might consider making five 2D images side by side?

Comment: have a look on this: http://personalpages.manchester.ac.uk/staff/d.h.foster/Tutorial_HSI2RGB/Tutorial_HSI2RGB.html

Comment: You could try Principal Component Analysis to reduce the dimensionality.

Comment: You may want to look at this: https://personalpages.manchester.ac.uk/staff/d.h.foster/Research/My_PDFs/Foster_Amano_JOSAA_19.pdf